# How can I debug what's failing in a Wine application?

Tags: 11.10, wine, debugging, photoshop

I've been able to get Photoshop CS5 installed on Wine. It also runs pretty well, but it throws a fatal exception when starting up:

[image]

Log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/817056/

Using the error log linked above, how can I find out what's going wrong? Photoshop doesn't actually die after this exception, but there are some oddities that occur with the program which I'd like to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, `winetricks nocrashdialog` fixes it. For the win.